# Json Objects AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

Well, i need to access some information inside of array that is inside of another array in Json Format.

more specific like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "PowerRanger",
    "description": "BLUE",
    "connections": 
    [ {"id": 123,"megazordName": "Fer","isSet": true},
      {"id": 456,"megazordName": "Alg","isSet": false}
    ]
    },{
     "id": 2,
     "name": "PowerRanger",
     "description": "RED",
     "connections": 
    [ {"id": 789,"megazordName": "Tes","isSet": false},
      {"id": 369,"megazordName": "EXp","isSet": true}
    ]
    },{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "PowerRanger",
    "description": "WHITE",
    "connections": 
    [ {"id": 258,"megazordName": "Ref","isSet": false},
      {"id": 147,"megazordName": "Mob","isSet": false}
    ]
    }
]
```

And i need to disable all the "megazordName" 's  when only ONE is selected (more specifically with checkbox).
Need some help :)

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YQjN8sXeUrQnSjTPIyOT?p=preview). 
How can i do it?

Comment: so, where is problem?

Comment: checkout underscore.js for searching through arrays.

Comment: @Sofia are you try something?

Comment: yeah, i builded an controller and the html , but it's not working right.

Comment: so show it and we can help

Comment: Providing code that isn't working right is what this site is all about. It is far better to show it than for us to guess at what you are trying to do. Also, providing a demo of your code, even if it throws errors is helpful

Comment: here's a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/YQjN8sXeUrQnSjTPIyOT?p=preview

Comment: @SofiaLunkes The reason Grundy has asked you to put it in your question here is because if the plunker goes, this question is useless, but, if you put it in the question, if it's resolved, then it may help other people out. Please add your code to your question. :)

Comment: @SofiaLunkes, can you explain what you want do? what _connections_ should be in select? all possibly or just some?

Comment: @SofiaLunkes, try see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Brq1IQZFyL0t2mhq4Lp?p=preview), possibly it what you want

Comment: actually , i just want to show all the megazord's in the connections array. I want an option to check one checkbox and then check them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got one solution but it is not 100% what you want .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
        .check-disabled-true {
            color: gray
        }

        .check-disabled-false {
            color: black
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        angular.module("atpModule", [])
                .controller("atpCtrl", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.selectedPrizemoney = 'Select one';
                    $scope.isdisabled=true;
                    $scope.atp = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "PowerRanger",
    "description": "BLUE",
    "connections": 
    [ {"id": 123,"megazordName": "Fer","isSet": true},
      {"id": 456,"megazordName": "Alg","isSet": false}
    ]
    },{
     "id": 2,
     "name": "PowerRanger",
     "description": "RED",
     "connections": 
    [ {"id": 789,"megazordName": "Tes","isSet": false},
      {"id": 369,"megazordName": "EXp","isSet": true}
    ]
    },{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "PowerRanger",
    "description": "WHITE",
    "connections": 
    [ {"id": 258,"megazordName": "Ref","isSet": false},
      {"id": 147,"megazordName": "Mob","isSet": false}
    ]
    }]


                    $scope.shouldBeDisabled = function (item) {
                        if (item.connections!= $scope.selectedPrizemoney) {                          
                            return true;
                        } else {                          
                            return false;
                        }
                    };
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="atpModule" ng-controller="atpCtrl">

    <div id="atpPanel" class="panel">
        <h4 class="panel-header">ENABLE/DISABLE CHECKBOXES USING ANGULAR JS</h4>
        <hr/>
        <h5 class="panel-header">Select the connection:</h5>


        <select ng-model="selectedPrizemoney"  ng-options=" items.megazordName for items in atp[0].connections">
            <option value="" disabled="">Select one</option>

        </select>
        <hr/>
        <div ng-repeat="item in apt.connections">
            <p class="check-disabled-{{shouldBeDisabled(item)}}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{item.megazordName}}" 
                     value="{{item.megazordName}}" ng-disabled="shouldBeDisabled(item)">{{item.megazordName}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```